# Connect to Office365 via backend service using OAuth2 in NON interactive way (bar initial setup)

Tags: imap, background-process, azure-ad-msal

I have a background service which reads & sends from a mailbox. It is created in a web ui, but after the schedule is created and mailbox set, it should run automatically, without further user prompt.

I have used the various combinations of the MSAL and both public and confidential clients (either would be acceptable as the server can maintain the client secret.

I have used the EWS client and got that working, but there is a note that the client_credentials flow won't work for IMAP/POP/SMTP.

I have a small console app working, but each time it runs, it needs to login interactively, and so long as I don't restart the application, it will keep authenticating, and I can call the AquireTokenSilently.

**The Question**

How can I make the MSAL save the tokens/data such that when it next runs, I can authenticate without user interaction again? I can store whatever is needed to make this work when the user authenticates, but I don't know what that should be nor how to reinstate it to make a new request, if the console app is restarted.

**The Code**

```
    internal async Task<string> Test()
    {
        PublicClientApplication =
        PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create( "5896de31-e251-460c-9dc2-xxxxxxxxxxxx" )
            .WithRedirectUri( "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient" )
            .WithAuthority( AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"] )
            .Build();

        //var scopes = new string[] { "email", "offline_access", "profile", "User.Read", "Mail.Read" };
        var scopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All" };

        var accounts = await PublicClientApplication.GetAccountsAsync();
        var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

        AuthenticationResult authResult;
        if (firstAccount == null )
        {
            authResult = await PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive( scopes ).ExecuteAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            //The firstAccount is null when the console app is run again
            authResult = await PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent( scopes, firstAccount ).ExecuteAsync();
        }
                                             
        if(authResult == null)
        {
            authResult = await PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive( scopes ).ExecuteAsync();
        }

        MailBee.Global.LicenseKey = "MN120-569E9E8D9E5B9E8D9EC8C4BC83D3-D428"; // (demo licence only)
        MailBee.ImapMail.Imap imap = new MailBee.ImapMail.Imap();

        var xOAuthkey = MailBee.OAuth2.GetXOAuthKeyStatic( authResult.Account.Username, authResult.AccessToken );
        imap.Connect( "imap.outlook.com", 993 );
        imap.Login( null, xOAuthkey, AuthenticationMethods.SaslOAuth2, AuthenticationOptions.None, null );
        imap.SelectFolder( "INBOX" );
        var count = imap.MessageCount.ToString();
        return authResult.AccessToken;

    }
```

It feels very much like a step missed, which can store the information to make subsequent requests and I would love a pointer in the right direction please.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your PublicClientApplication, it provides you with the UserTokenCache.

UserTokenCache implements interface ITokenCache, which defines events to subscribe to token cache serialization requests as well as methods to serialize or de-serialize the cache at various formats.

You should create your own TokenCacheBuilder, which can store the tokens in file/memory/database etc.. and then use the events to subscribe to to token cache request.

An example of a FileTokenCacheProvider:

```
public abstract class MsalTokenCacheProviderBase
{
    private Microsoft.Identity.Client.ITokenCache cache;
    private bool initialized = false;
    public MsalTokenCacheProviderBase()
    {
    }

    public void InitializeCache(Microsoft.Identity.Client.ITokenCache tokenCache)
    {
        if (initialized)
            return;
        cache = tokenCache;
        cache.SetBeforeAccessAsync(OnBeforeAccessAsync);
        cache.SetAfterAccessAsync(OnAfterAccessAsync);
        initialized = true;
    }

    private async Task OnAfterAccessAsync(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        if (args.HasStateChanged)
        {
            if (args.HasTokens)
            {
                await StoreAsync(args.Account.HomeAccountId.Identifier,
                    args.TokenCache.SerializeMsalV3()).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            else
            {
                // No token in the cache. we can remove the cache entry
                await DeleteAsync<bool>(args.SuggestedCacheKey).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task OnBeforeAccessAsync(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.SuggestedCacheKey))
        {
            byte[] tokenCacheBytes = await GetAsync<byte[]>(args.SuggestedCacheKey).ConfigureAwait(false);
            args.TokenCache.DeserializeMsalV3(tokenCacheBytes, shouldClearExistingCache: true);
        }
    }

    protected virtual Task OnBeforeWriteAsync(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public abstract Task StoreAsync<T>(string key, T value);

    public abstract Task DeleteAsync<T>(string key);

    public abstract Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key);

    public abstract Task ClearAsync();

}
```

And the MsalFileTokenCacheProvider:

```
 public sealed class MsalFileTokenCacheProvider : MsalTokenCacheProviderBase
{
    private string basePath;
    public MsalFileTokenCacheProvider(string basePath)
    {
        this.basePath = basePath;
    }
    public override Task ClearAsync()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override Task DeleteAsync<T>(string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Key MUST have a value");
        }
        string path = Path.Combine(basePath, key + ".json");
        if (File.Exists(path))
            File.Delete(path);
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    public override Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Key MUST have a value");
        }
        string path = Path.Combine(basePath, key + ".json");
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            T value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(File.ReadAllText(path));
            return Task.FromResult(value);
        }
        else
            return Task.FromResult(default(T));
    }

    public override Task StoreAsync<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        string contents = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        string path = Path.Combine(basePath, key + ".json");

        File.WriteAllText(path, contents);
        return Task.FromResult(value);
    }
}
```

So based on your code you will have:

```
PublicClientApplication =
    PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create( "5896de31-e251-460c-9dc2-xxxxxxxxxxxx" )
        .WithRedirectUri( "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient" )
        .WithAuthority( AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"] )
        .Build();

MsalFileTokenCacheProvider cacheProvider = new MsalFileTokenCacheProvider("TokensFolder");
cacheProvider.InitializeCache(PublicClientApplication.UserTokenCache);


    //var scopes = new string[] { "email", "offline_access", "profile", "User.Read", "Mail.Read" };
    var scopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All" };

// when you call the below code, the PublicClientApplication will use your token cache 
//provider in order to get the required Account. You should also use the 
//PublicClientApplication.GetAccountAsync(key) which will use the token cache provider for 
//the specific account that you want to get the token. If there is an account you could 
//just call the AcquireTokenSilent method. The acquireTokenSilent method will take care of the token expiration and will refresh if needed. 
//Please bare in mind that in some circumstances the AcquireTokenSilent method will fail and you will have to use the AcquireTokenInteractive method again. //Example of this would be when the user changes password, or has removed the access to your Application via their Account.

        var accounts = await PublicClientApplication.GetAccountsAsync();
        var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
```

Please refer to the following documentation from Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization